# How to convert coeffecient multiplying $t$ in a trig function (e.g. $\sin(bt)$) into Hertz?

Tags: trigonometry

How to convert coeffecient multiplying $t$ in a trig function (e.g. $\sin(bt)$) into Hertz?

For example, if I want a machine to produce waves in my bathtub such that the waves follow the function $\sin(4.224 t)$, but the machine operates in Hertz (Hz), how do I make this conversion?

The period of $\sin(4.224 t)$ is $2\pi / 4.224$, and so the frequency is $4.224/ 2\pi$. I know that much, but I'm not sure how to convert this frequency (which seems to be unitless) to Hz...

From searching online I've found an equation for "angular frequency", $w=2\pi f$, but I'm not sure what the $w$ and $f$ would be in this context (also not sure if this is even relevant/usable in this situation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hertz is $s^{-1}$ in other words "per second".  Sensibly, the argument to $\sin$ will be unitless but assuming that $t$ is in seconds then $b$ should be in $s^{-1}$.  For frequency, you want whole waves per second, so considering that the period of $\sin$ is $2 \pi$, the frequency will be $f = \frac{b}{2 \pi}$.  This is also $s^{-1}$ but Hz is traditionally used.  The angular speed $\omega$, which is just $b$ for you is larger, by a factor of $2 \pi$, because it is measured in radians per second rather than whole revolutions.

This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency) uses angular frequency, angular speed,or a few other terms and reserves angular velocity for the vector.  This is consistent with linear motion.

The main distinction that I am trying to make is between measuring whole revolutions or radians.  In day to day life, rotational rate is typically measured in revolutions per time unit.  E.g. records have typical speeds of $33 \frac{1}{3}$, $45$, or $78$ rpm and tachometers in cars also use rpm (or a multiple of it).  However, if you see $\sin(\omega t)$ then $\omega$ will be in radians per unit time; probably second but it could be other units as long as they match $t$.  $\omega t$ needs to be dimensionless and in radians.  I guess that rotational rate could be measured in degrees per unit time but I have never seen that.

Radians are often treated as if they were a unit but they are not really.  They are not arbitrary in the way that the metre or the yard is.  A measurement in radians is just a number. So, radians per second is actually just $s^{-1}$ and we could use Hz.  However, because other measures of angles are common, degrees or revolutions, we generally feel the need to emphasize that radians are being used. Hz is usually reserved for whole waves per second.

Becquerel  is also $s^{-1}$  but it is used for radioactive decays per second. More units are used than are really necessary.

Comment: Thank you so much! So in my example, $f=4.224/2\pi$, and $\omega = 4.224$? Also, I'm a bit confused as to what you meant by your last sentence in the first paragraph. What is actually the same thing?

Comment: One more question: I don't think angular velocity and angular frequency is the same thing? You said that $\omega$ is angular velocity, but according to this wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angular_frequency, $\omega$ is angular frequency, not velocity. (Not arguing with you, just trying to understand, thank you for the help)

Comment: Yes, I was a little sloppy.  The distinction is in the article that you link. As with linear motion, velocity should be used for a vector rather than a scalar.However, angular frequency does not sound familiar to me.

Comment: I edited my answer in response to your comments.  I hope that it is clearer now.  Despite that Wikipedia article, I don't like "angular frequency" as I like to reserve "frequency" for whole cycles and not radians.  You could try Physics SE as physicists are more consistent with terminology and notation than mathematicians.